# How to import font in PhpStorm

Tags: fonts, phpstorm

I am making HTML Emailer. The content of the emailer is of **Raleway** font. that's why I want to import Google's **Raleway** fonts in PhpStorm.

How can I do so?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why do you want to import it? To use it as font for your code? Or in a project? What language is your project? Please be clear in your question. **PS:** don't use it as font for your programming, you probably want a *monospace* font for that.

Comment: i have edited question

Comment: Still it isn't clear to me. An HTML emailer. How do you want to use the font? Must the user see the font in the received email? Are you using an email library? How are the emails generated?

Comment: `font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif.`i have written this syntax to use my contents' font as Raleway . yes.. user must see the fonts which i have given in my HTML Email. and I am not using any email library. as Outlook doesn't support any third party library.

Comment: I still do not understand what do you mean by "importing" here. 1) It's a font from Google Fonts services 2) You just doing HTML/CSS .. so what's the problem here? Just follow instructions from Google Fonts and use it. 3) *"as Outlook doesn't support any third party library."* Same here -- what this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to add fonts to the IntelliJ IDE directly. You should install the font to your OS.

1. For **Ubuntu**:

- Download the font (e.g. .otf),
- Unzip it,
- and then install by **double-clicking** on the font file and push '**install**' btn,
- or alternatively: put your fonts in **/usr/share/fonts/opentype** and update the fonts cache with `sudo fc-cache -f -v`

2. For the **Windows**:

- Open the Windows **Control Panel**.
- Select Appearance and Personalization.
- At the bottom, select **Fonts**. ...
- To add a font, simply drag the font file into the **font window**.
- To remove fonts, just right click the chosen font and select **Delete**.
- Click **Yes** when prompted.

3. Go to the PhpStorm (or whatever IntelliJ) *Settings -> Fonts*, and remove a tick from the 'Show only monospaced fonts' checkbox.

Then you'll see a full list of fonts of your system in the dropdown below.
If there is no your installed font, you should restart your IDE and repeat the 3-rd step.

Enjoy ;)